# How can I git pull ignored files?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, dvcs, drupal-8

For my Drupal 8 installation I want to use the following workflow:

1) On the local machine installs and updates are done with Composer. Composer files are then pushed to Bitbucket.

2) On the remote server I have a staging folder in which I pull the composer files and do a composer install.

3) On the same server I want to have another folder for the production site. Here I clone the staging folder and later pull all its changes.

The problem now is, that Drupal core and modules folders (those installed by Composer) are in gitignore. So they are not pulled from staging to production. How can I track/version control the WHOLE staging folder and pull changes to production? If I delete the gitignore files I suppose they will be pulled again next time from Bitbucket.

EDIT: This article describes a solution, but I don't really understand how it works with this CI server: http://nuvole.org/blog/2016/aug/19/optimal-deployment-workflow-composer-based-drupal-8-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify `.gitignore` and push&pull again in you steps:

1. On local machine, delete the Drupal core and modules folders in `.gitignore` and then add & commit & push again.
2. On the remote server of staging folder, pull the changes.
3. On the remote server of production site, pull the changes from staging folder.

**option2:**

1. Protect `.gitignore` file in staging folder, even pull from bitbucket the .gitignore will not be overwirtted as below:

   `git update-index --skip-worktree .gitignore`
2. Modify `.gitignore` file and add some useful files in staging folder.

Comment: But this is one of the main reasons to use Composer, you don't have to unnecessarily fill your repository with ten thousands of files...

Comment: If you want part of the files are version controlled, you can use wildcards in `.gitignore` to filter the ones you want to ignore.

Comment: This is not the point - I want some files to be ignored on the local machine, but no files ignored on the remote server, so that they can be pulled from staging to production.

Comment: As the whole version control, it’s impossible. Because if you ignore the files in the first step at local machine, the remote repo won’t exist the ignored files. But for the manually way: you can modify `.gitignore` from staging folder and add useful files in it. Then production pull the changes from staging.

Comment: That's what I thought about too, but with the next pull from Bitbucket the `.gitignore` will be overwritten again. What do you think about using `git add -f .` like proposed in the other answer?

Comment: You can protect the `.gitignore` which I added the method in my answer.

Comment: I will test it this week ;)

Comment: So I read more about the topic regarding option 2 and I wonder why not adding 1) `.gitignore` to `.gitignore` itself or 2) to `.git/info/exclude` and if there is a difference between these three possibilities...

Comment: If you set `git update-index --skip-worktree .gitignore`, .gitignore will not be updated in working tree. So before you pull changes from bitbucket, you can set `git update-index --skip-worktree .gitignore`, after the pull, you can set `git update-index --no-skip-worktree .gitignore`. `.git/info/exclude` only ignore files locally, when you want to pull changes from staging to production, the `.git/info/exclude` will not updated in production folder.

Comment: Ok, thank you! The only information I found about the two possibilities I mentioned is that they can't be applied for tracked files, so they have to be untracked before with `git rm -r --cached filename`

Answer (score 1):

Commit the files and push to a different repository used for production, or to a branch/tag away from your main development branch (the downside with this latter approach is your repository can get big quickly). You can choose to override the gitignore configuration at staging time too, eg:

```
git add -f .
```

Alternatively, consider running the composer installation in production as part of your deployment process, or building a container image you can push (eg docker) and running that to help keep things as similar in dev and production as possible.

Comment: I think overriding gitignore is the best solution. I wonder why there is not more information around about this topic as this must be a usual issue...
And I heard that using composer in production is not really recommended...

Comment: I meant you run composer as part of the CI build process (whether this is automated or a manual step) that builds your application so that you are able to demonstrate the repeatability of your builds. If one of the answers you have got solves the problem don't forget to accept it!